# how to download pdf file with R from web (encode issue)

Tags: r, encode

I am trying to download a pdf file from a website using R. When I tried to to use the function browserURL, it only worked with the argument encodeIfNeeded = T. As a result, if I pass the same url to the function download.file, it returns "cannot open destfile 'downloaded/teste.pdf', reason 'No such file or directory", i.e., it cant find the correct url.

How do I correct the encode, in order for me to be able to download the file programatically?
I need to automate this, because there are more than a thousand files to download.

Here's a minimum reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


url <- "http://www.ouvidoriageral.sp.gov.br/decisoesLAI.html"
webpage <- read_html(url)

# scrapping hyperlinks
links_decisoes <- html_nodes(webpage,".borderTD a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

# creating full/correct url
full_links <- paste("http://www.ouvidoriageral.sp.gov.br/", links_decisoes, sep="" )

# browseURL only works with encodeIfNeeded = T
browseURL(full_links[1], encodeIfNeeded = T,
          browser = "C://Program Files//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe")
# returns an error
download.file(full_links[1], "downloaded/teste.pdf")
```

Comment: Does the folder "downloaded" exist in your working directory? `download.file` will not create new folders for you that don't already exist. What does `list.dirs(path = ".", recursive = FALSE)` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, the links to some of the files are not properly formatted as urls - they contain spaces and other special characters. In order to convert them you must use `url_escape()`, which should be available to you as loading rvest also loads xml2, which contains `url_escape()`.

Secondly, the path you are saving to is relative to your R home directory, but you are not telling R this. You either need the full path like this: `"C://Users/Manoel/Documents/downloaded/testes.pdf"`, or a relative path like this: `path.expand("~/downloaded/testes.pdf")`.

This code should do what you need:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# scraping hyperlinks
full_links <- "http://www.ouvidoriageral.sp.gov.br/decisoesLAI.html" %>%
               read_html()                                           %>%
               html_nodes(".borderTD a")                             %>%
               html_attr("href")                                     %>%
               url_escape()                                          %>%
               {paste0("http://www.ouvidoriageral.sp.gov.br/", .)}

# Looks at page in firefox
browseURL(full_links[1], encodeIfNeeded = T, browser = "firefox.exe")

# Saves pdf to "downloaded" folder if it exists
download.file(full_links[1], path.expand("~/downloaded/teste.pdf"))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. I only had to add mode="wb" to the function download.file, since I'm on Windows.

Comment: @AllanCameron: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thank you!